# R are not identified

Tags: android

I creating a map project.
Main Activity =

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    if (googleHarita == null) {
        googleHarita = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritafragment))
                .getMap();
```

R says "cannot resolve symbol *R*".
What can I do?

Comment: are u on eclipse or android studio ??

Comment: Question too rudimentary

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Build` option and select `Clean Project` option.

And then select `Rebuild`.